# Firebase iOS socket not reconnecting

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been experiencing an issue where at random I will stop receiving events on all of my apps observers. I have finally found that this occurs under 2 scenarios. A network disruption or the app being sent to the background. I have tried using `Database.database.goOnline()` to no avail. Are there any other methods to restoring the observers I have already registered?

When my program launches it makes a call to a few instances that have functions for observing the data that belongs to them. The data from the observer is then stored in the instance and views are then updated if they are currently present. In this way the data will be updated in the background and I can move between view controllers without load times. It seems as though these observers are timing out or something of the sort.

```
class Order {
    static let instance: Order = Order()

    var orders: [DataSnapshot] = []

    func watchOrders() {
        let orderRef = database.child("orders/\(AppData.instance.currentStore!.key)")
        orderRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot -> Void in
            self.orders.removeAll()
            let orders = snapshot.children
            while let order = orders.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                self.orders.append(order)
            }


              self.updateOrderViews()
            })
    }

    func updateOrderViews() {
        if let tillView = AppViews.instance.tillView {
            tillView.tillTable.reloadData()
        }
        if let tillFunctionView = AppViews.instance.tillFunctionView {
            tillFunctionView.calcTill()
        }
        if let tillReconcileView = AppViews.instance.tillReconcileView {
            tillReconcileView.calcTill()
        }
        if let dispatchView = AppViews.instance.dispatchView {
            dispatchView.loadDispatch()
        }
        if let dispatchRecapView = AppViews.instance.dispatchRecapView {
            dispatchRecapView.getDispatchedOrders()
        }
        if let managerView = AppViews.instance.managerView {
            managerView.getReport()
        }
        if let searchView = AppViews.instance.searchView {
            searchView.filterOrders()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not standard behavior; Firebase recovers from network disruptions. We can turn off wifi, then turn it back on and FB continues to operate. However, without seeing your code it's going to be hard to troubleshoot. Please review this guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)